# Вставить значение переменной в форму

Tags: javascript, html, input, форма

Всем привет! Нужна помощь.

Как присвоить значению Value в формах значение переменной? В итоге нужно чтобы в Value вставлялось рандомно число от 1 до 4

```html
<form method="post" action="http://123.php" name="x1" target="y1">
<input type="hidden" name="one" value="..."> 
<input type="hidden" name="two" value="...">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const valFrom1to4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1)) + 1;
input.setAttribute('value', valFrom1to4) // как атрибут
input.value = valFrom1to4; // как значение
```